# Spring Config Server and Client embedded in the same application

Tags: spring-cloud

I understand that the config server needs to be up to bootstrap any of its clients.

Is there any way we can embed both Spring config Server and client in the same application so that each application could protect its sensitive information easily? If it is possible, I will use server for reading properties from the git and client for the decryption.

Answer (score 1):

This flow works with me:

Step 1: Use only Config Server dependency:

`pom.xml`

```xml
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-server</artifactId>
</dependency>
```

Step 2: Enable Config Server via`@EnableConfigServer` annotation.

Step 3: In `bootstrap.yml` file (not `application.yml`), we will configure:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    config:
      server:
        # This flag indicates that the server should configure itself from its own remote repository
        bootstrap: true
        git:
          uri: https://github.com/your-git-account/your-config-repository
          username: user
          password: secret
          searchPaths: foo,bar*
          timeout: 10
        # prefix string to avoid conflicting with context/server path of application
        prefix: config
```

Step 4: Remove all configurations related to Config Server in `application.yml` file.

Comment: Hi, if i want to use native profile instead of git. how should i configure.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, all that you'd need to do is add the `@EnableConfigServer` annotation and set `spring.cloud.config.server.bootstrap=true`. For detail see *[Embedding the Config Server](http://cloud.spring.io/spring-cloud-config/spring-cloud-config.html#_embedding_the_config_server)* and [`spring-cloud-config` issue 100](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/100).